# PHP each() function replacement

Tags: php, function, replace, each, deprecated

I read a textbook and it said each() function is deprecated. The author has recommend his own replacement for each() function called myEach() as following:

```
function myEach(&$array)
{
    $key = key($array);
    $result = ($key === null) ? false :
              [$key, current($array), 'key', 'value' => current($array)];
    next($array);
    return $result;
}
```

Is the part: `[$key, current($array), 'key', 'value' => current($array)];` wrong?

Comment: [Read that fine manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php#refsect1-function.each-returnvalues)

Comment: With only 2 results in the array, it doesn't produce the same behavior as the native `each`, therefore you need 4. It's not about can or can't, it's about intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is correct as `each` is deprecated : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

The 3rd argument is wrong, it should be `key => $key`

```
[$key, current($array), 'key' => $key, 'value' => current($array)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is function myEach(&$array), but
myEach(&$array) is not  each($array) . I tried to applicate it in a Typesettercms-plugin with an error , probably because &$array is not $array)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).